# BadTokenException error fixed for Spinner but now TextViews not showing up in layout. How can I fix both problems?

Tags: android, layout, spinner

I have a dialog with a spinner.

```
        AlertDialog.Builder customDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.jquery_dialog, null);
        final EditText idTxt = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.idName);
        final Spinner themeSpinner = (Spinner) view
                .findViewById(R.id.themeSpinner);
        final CheckBox headerChk = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.headerChk);
        final CheckBox footerChk = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.footerChk);
        final RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup) view
                .findViewById(R.id.jqmNavigation);
        customDialog.setView(idTxt);
        customDialog.setView(headerChk);
        customDialog.setView(footerChk);
        themeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                themes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.themes);
                theme = themes[arg2];
                Toast.makeText(NewFile.this, theme, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

When I click the Spinner I get the error

```
04-25 18:01:56.299: E/AndroidRuntime(21639331): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
```

I fixed this problem by changing the LayoutInflater code to

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(MyActivity.this);
```

which fixes my Spinner error but now none of the TextViews in my Dialog show up. How Can I fix both problems?

EDIT

```
public void jqueryMobileDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder customDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.jquery_dialog, null);
        final EditText idTxt = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.idName);
        final Spinner themeSpinner = (Spinner) view
                .findViewById(R.id.themeSpinner);
        final CheckBox headerChk = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.headerChk);
        final CheckBox footerChk = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.footerChk);
        final RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup) view
                .findViewById(R.id.jqmNavigation);
        customDialog.setView(idTxt);
        customDialog.setView(headerChk);
        customDialog.setView(footerChk);
        themeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                themes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.themes);
                theme = themes[arg2];
                Toast.makeText(NewFile.this, theme, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The layout inflater needs to come from a context with the right to draw to the screen.  Only the current activity has this.  SO calling getApplicationContext().getLayoutInflater will never work-  the application context doesn't have permission.  Use the getLayoutInflater of your current activity instead.

There are two other times this can happen.  One is if you're popping up a dialog too quickly (before your activity has the right to display).  The only solution I've found for this is to send a message to yourself to retry in 100 ms when that happens, and retry a couple of times.  This will happen if, for example, you try to show your dialog in onCreate.

The other is when your dialog tries to show at the same time your activity loses the foreground.  There is no solution for this, because you don't know if/when you're going to become the foreground app again.  Here you want to catch and ignore.  Note that this may also happen around rotation and other config changes that terminate and restart the activity.

Comment: Changed my LayoutInflater code but now it crashes as soon as the Dialog attempts to display. See Edit. Thanks.